# self replicating file, retrieve name of executed script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

Is there a way to change `os.path.basename(__file__)` to the name of a file executed within the current running script?

I've created a simple self replicating file. It starts by accessing the root directory. It then sorts through all writeable sub-directories and picks a random one out of the list. After that it writes a .py file with  random string of numbers as it's name.  It then uses `os.path.basename(__file__)` to retrieve the file name and copy the lines to the newly written file. After all that is said and done, it executes the newly created file which repeats the process again. However, on the second round through, it retains `__file__` for the original file name and not the newly generated file.

This portion stores the original directory path and file name

```
import os
import random

orig_dir = os.getcwd()
orig_file = os.path.basename(__file__)
```

This portion is the file writing process and execution of the new file. 
**NOTE: the path variable is a randomly picked sub-directory of the root that contains the newly written file.**

```
file_create = open(rand_name, "w")
file_create.close()
file_create = open(rand_name, "a")
os.chdir(orig_dir)
copy_file = open(orig_file, "r")
for line in copy_file.readlines():
    file_create.write(line)

file_create.close()
copy_file.close()
os.chdir(path)

exec(open(rand_name).read())
```

**UPDATE:**
I'm posting the entire script below. There are a few brute and ugly approaches I too to get it working, but I'm more focused on the problem at hand.

```
import os
import random

orig_dir = os.getcwd()
orig_file = os.path.basename(__file__)

for loop in range(20):
    os.chdir("..")
root = os.getcwd()

direct = []
for items in os.listdir():
    if os.path.isdir(items) and os.access(items, os.W_OK) and os.access(items, os.R_OK):
        direct.append(items)

path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), random.choice(direct))
rand_name = str(random.randint(1, 10000000000)) + ".py"
os.chdir(path)
print(path)

# prevents the creation of a duplicate file name in the same location.
# If it is, loops the name generator until a valid name is generated
while True:
    if os.path.isfile(rand_name):
        rand_name = str(random.randint(1, 10000000000)) + ".py"
    else:
        break


file_create = open(rand_name, "w")
file_create.close()
file_create = open(rand_name, "a")
os.chdir(orig_dir)
copy_file = open(orig_file, "r")
for line in copy_file.readlines():
    file_create.write(line)


file_create.close()
copy_file.close()
os.chdir(path)
os.execl(rand_name, ''),
```

`os.exec(path, '')` is the last solution I tried but it started to return `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`. I tried to run it with sudo privileges as well and it returned the same permission error.

Comment: I'm hesitant to answer this, as I'm not sure what reasonable use case this has, but the solution is to use `os.exec_` not `exec`.

Comment: It's purely out of curiosity. I'm still new to python and it's my first language. I tried out os.exec and ran into this: 

`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`.

I'm not sure why. The chosen directories are both readable and writeable.